# Creative liberty or error in dropping "was"

Tags: syntactic-analysis

This sentence is about the battle of Agincourt, and how the combat involved lifting up the visors on enemy soldiers' helmets to expose their faces. It reads

> That's how hundreds of men died; their last sight on earth a dagger's
>   point.

It sounds a little awkward to me, but maybe I'm just not familiar enough with all the nuances of this writing style. Maybe it's grammatically correct, but to me I think I would add a "was" before "dagger's point"

**Question:** Is this an example of the author taking creative liberty with the sentence structure, or does this sentence structure belong to an existing convention, and if so what is that convention? Is it conventional to have an **implied** was?

Comment: Perhaps add a comma after *earth*, but otherwise it's fine as written.

Comment: @Lawrence This is spot on (including the comma).  The grammar is fine.

Comment: Not even a comma is needed. It works for me the way it is. The "elided,"  "implied" or "missing" word, if any, is not *was* but ***being***. HTH.

Comment: @Kris *being* would fit better with a comma in place of the semicolon. With the given punctuation (with or without the extra comma after *earth*), *was* fits better.

Comment: @Lawrence The writer's intent was *being* not *was*, the second clause extends the first, it's not entirely independent. It is meant to add poignancy to the first (main) clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that you can use **was** here—at least not unambiguously.

Looking only at the sentence itself (because there is no other context), **that's** can either stand for **that was** or **that is**.

If it stands for **that is**, then adding **was** wouldn't be correct; nor would adding **is** be correct.

The use of the semicolon in this construction, and how the text that comes after it is phrased, is suggestive of two independent clauses. Except that the second part doesn't work on its own. (Which is why you think that **was** should be added.)

But I believe the sentence can be tweaked to clear up the issue:

> That's how hundreds of men died**: with** their last sight on earth **being** a dagger's point.

I replaced the semicolon with a colon (an em dash could also have been used), making it clear that the second part of the sentence is not an independent clause. I then added **with**, as that better serves to define what came before, and used **being** to get around the problem with tense (because it works equally with either **that was** or **that is**).

---

**Update**: To more specifically address the question, I do think that some small liberties are being taken—but the question is if they are acceptable or not. It's a style choice to allow the second clause that can be considered incorrect in some strict interpretations.

Nobody is failing to understand the sentence, and modifying it will change its emotional reading, so it works at that level. You really can't know if you *can* omit such words in this type of situation. It's a matter of style and personal choice. (Assuming it's intentional in the first place.)

Comment: I think the OP meant adding *was* after *earth*. That's not problematic.

Comment: @Lawrence I think Jason makes a good case. Just not sure I agree with the colon.

Comment: While this certainly addresses the grammar of the sentence, it has to be said that the result is nowhere near as immediate and powerful as the original

Comment: That is certainly interesting, and I thank you for explaining that far, but I'm still a little confused. If the writer isn't using any creative liberties and the sentence is fine grammatically, then how do we know whether or not we can omit a word like **being** or **was**?

Comment: @ArashHowaida I have updated my answer. In short, if it's intentional, it's a matter of style.

Comment: @JasonBassford I've never seen that's as a contraction of "that was", only "is" and "has". Could you please clarify?

Comment: @bookmanu Are you saying that it's impossible to form a contraction out of  *that was true* without changing the tense from the past to the present? (I'm not saying you're wrong. It's an interesting point.) In any case, that would just make the use of *earth was* all the more questionable.

Comment: @JasonBassford No, I was saying that when I see "that's", I only associate it with "that is" or "that has" depending on context. I'm not sure an apostrophe -s can be used to replace "was". In your answer you wrote "...that's can either stand for that was or that is."

Comment: @JasonBassford - you wrote “Looking only at the sentence itself (because there is no other context), that's can either stand for that was or that is.” you said it could ‘possibly/either ‘stand for “that was” from what I understood. I have never seen this. Could you reference it please?

Comment: @bookmanu What I meant is, if you look at "that's" it can be interpreted as either "that is" or "that was". "That was how hundreds of men died." "That is how hundreds of men died." Only be looking at the tense of verbs in surrounding text (which is not provided) could you infer if the event is supposed to be a description of a past event or a present event. A discussion of the validity of the contraction of "that was" to "that's" is something too complicated for comments.

Comment: OK @JasonBassford, just that I’ve never seen “that’s” as a contraction of “that was”. Hence my ‘argument’ :)

Comment: @bookmanu I agree that it's puzzling. Perhaps I should pose it as a new question. :)

Answer (score 1):

That sentence, without "was," is a fine example of potent phrasing. "Be" verb forms are common and motionless. "Is" and "was" are often omitted (where they are understood or assumed) in every form of writing and speech, from poetry to technical papers.

A little googling will turn up examples. Often in parallel constructions, used to emphasize the contrast between ideas, a second "be" verb is omitted:

"To err is human, to forgive [is] divine."

Check "ellipses" or "elliptical construction" for more examples.